# Call php function () to display name before each icons

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, gpio

I want to diplay the name of each relay before the image on.png or off.png.
I have 2 pages:

```
switch.php and functions.php
```

switch.php, displays icons on or off for each relay, reading the gpio status. functions.php displays the name of each relay.

I don't know how to call function like r$i(), in switch.php to display something like :

```
relay0<img id='button_0' src='images/off.png' alt='off'/><br>
relay1<img id='button_1' src='images/off.png' alt='off'/>
```

There are my scripts:

```
// switch.php
<?php
 $status = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($status); $i++) {
    //set the pin's mode to output and read them
    system("gpio mode ".$i." out");
    exec ("gpio read ".$i, $status[$i], $return );
    if ($status[$i][0] == 0 ) {
        echo ("<img id='relay_".$i."' src='images/off.png' alt='off'/><br>");
    }
    if ($status[$i][0] == 1 ) {
        echo ("<img id='relay_".$i."' src='images/on.png' alt='on'/><br>");
    }    
 }
```

and

```
// function.php
<?php
function r0(){
   echo "relay0";
}
function r1(){
   echo "relay1";
}
function r2(){
   echo "relay2";
}
function r3(){
   echo "relay3";
}
?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `function.php` file is supposed to be replaced with more functionality in the future, you could do something like this:

```
function r0() {
    echo 'relay0';
}

function r1() {
    echo 'relay1';
}


$i = 1;
$fn = "r$i"; // string containing function name
$fn(); // this will call function 'r1'

call_user_func($fn); // this will also call 'r1'
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you Marios. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

if the ID of the relays match with the ID of the buttons you don't need the function.php script, try something like this:

**switch.php**

```
<?php
 $status = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($status); $i++) {
    //set the pin's mode to output and read them
    system("gpio mode ".$i." out");
    exec ("gpio read ".$i, $status[$i], $return );
    if ($status[$i][0] == 0 ) {
    echo ("relay$i<img id='relay_".$i."' src='images/off.png' alt='off'/><br>");
    }
    if ($status[$i][0] == 1 ) {
    echo ("relay$i<img id='relay_".$i."' src='images/on.png' alt='on'/><br>");
    }    
 }
```

NOTE: when you use double quotes don't need to concat the variables with the dots.

I hope this help you.

UPDATE: Another aproach is use an array, look...

```
<?php

$relays = array();
$relays[] = "A";
$relays[] = "B";
$relays[] = "C";
$relays[] = "D";

$status = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($status); $i++) {
    //set the pin's mode to output and read them
    system("gpio mode ".$i." out");
    exec ("gpio read ".$i, $status[$i], $return );
    if ($status[$i][0] == 0 ) {
        echo ("{$relays[$i]}<img id='relay_".$i."' src='images/off.png' alt='off'/><br>");
    }
    if ($status[$i][0] == 1 ) {
        echo ("{$relays[$i]}<img id='relay_".$i."' src='images/on.png' alt='on'/><br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Synkronice! It could help me, but each function will call a different icon for each relay (relay0 light, relay1 heater,...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable functions,

```
$function = 'r'.$i; //set function name
$function(); //call the function
```

more info: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php